# What is the maximum size of PSDataStreams class or the Powershell.Streams property?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to execute around 40000 commandlets in Powershell and this is my code.

```
rmcommand = new PSCommand();
rmcommand.AddScript(shellcommand);
rmcommand.Commands.Add("Out-String");
powershell.Commands = rmcommand;            
Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();
```

Here, shellcommand is the command to execute and I pass it to the method each time. Now, let us say all the commandlets give an error. So these errors are stored in powershell.streams property. What is the maximum size of this property? Because, after executing around 23000 commandlets, I think the stream gets full and the execution stalls. At the same time, if I read the stream after each invoke, all 40000 commandlets are executing fine. So I assume the stream is getting full. Is it the case? Or, am I missing anything?

Comment: Not sure there is a buffer size limit per stream, but there is a memory limit per shell.  I believe the default for V3 is 1024MB,  and for V2 it was only 150MB.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me what will happen if the maximum memory limit per shell is exceeded? Is any exception thrown? How do I find out how much memory my shell is consuming?

Comment: Normally you get an OutOfMemory exception, but I've never seen the case of overrunning the Error stream like that.

Comment: Also, assuming the output of a commandlet is a part of the memory that is consumed, will the output of the first commandlet continue to consume memory even after the second commandlet is executed? If so, how do I clear that memory?

Comment: You'd clear memory by doing and .EndInvoke() to clear the output buffer.